# Bulk Import .CSV to SQL table

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server-2008-r2, bulk-import

I have a bizare problem with importing .csv files into sql table. 
The bulk import from .csv does not give any erros and completes fine, but the data is not imported into SQL table. There is data in .csv

However, when i open the .csv in excel and save it again as .csv, try bulk import, check the tables and the data is there.

Any ideas of what it could be? And if it encoding issue, how can i check the encoding on the .csv file before importing or force sql to import no matter what.

Thanks.

Comment: Compare the before and after CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the reject and issues only we have log and bad file while
loading from a file,

1. Your log file will have the reason behind reject
2. Your bad file will have a sample rejected record

For your question, when you open it in excel and it's working : this is
nothing but format of some fields (may be date columns) will change when
you open it in excel which may suits your table structure.

try giving MAX ERROR 0 and run,

```
BULK INSERT OrdersBulk 
    FROM 'c:\file.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    )
```

Hope this helps